# Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in C:\xampp\login.php on line 24

Tags: php, html, mysql

El error me indica que es en la línea de la condicional `if`, en la cual dice `if($result->num_rows> 0)` y no entiendo por qué. Mi código es el siguiente:

```
   <?php
        require_once("sesion.class.php");
        $sesion = new sesion();
        if( isset($_POST["iniciar"]) )
        {
            $usuario = $_POST["usuario"];
            $password = $_POST["password"];
    
            if(validarUsuario($usuario,$password) == true)
            {
                $sesion->set("usuarioactual",$usuario);
                header("location: index.php");
            }
            else
            {
        }
    }
    function validarUsuario($usuario, $password)
    {
      $conexion = new mysqli("localhost","root","","cliente");
      $consulta = "select clave from usuarios where usuario = '$usuario';";
      $result = $conexion->query($consulta);
    
      if($result->num_rows> 0){
    
        $fila = $result->fetch_assoc();
        if( strcmp($password,$fila["clave"]) == 0 )
          return true;
        else
          return false;
      }
      else
          return false;
    }
    ?>

<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>login in</title>
</head>
<body>
<div class="wrapper fadeInDown">
  <div id="formContent">
    <h2>Log in</h2>
      <form method="post" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>">
        <input type="text" name="usuario" placeholder="Usuario">
        <input type="password" name="password"  placeholder="Password">
        <button class="fadeIn fourth" name="iniciar">Iniciar</button>
      </form>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Puede que `$result` sea `false` porque la consulta falló. Por eso no debes pasar a leer recursos sin antes verificarlos con algo como esto: `if ($result) { $fila = $result->fetch_assoc(); // ... etc } else { //algo falló en la consulta, actuar en consecuencia }` Estás cometiendo el típico error de lo que yo llamo *programación ingenua u optimista*, es decir, programar pensando que los errores o problemas no existen y por tanto no afrontándolos.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Puede que `$result` sea `false` porque la consulta falló. Por eso no debes pasar a leer recursos sin antes verificarlos.

Estás cometiendo el típico error de lo que yo llamo *programación ingenua u optimista*, es decir, programar pensando que los errores o problemas no existen y por tanto no afrontándolos.

Debes verificar todo aquello que pueda fallar:

```
function validarUsuario($usuario, $password)
{
    $mysqli = new mysqli("localhost","root","","cliente");
    if ($mysqli) {
        $sql = "select clave from usuarios where usuario = '$usuario';";
        if ($result = $mysqli->query($sql)) {
            if($result->num_rows > 0) {
                $fila = $result->fetch_assoc();
                return strcmp($password,$fila["clave"]) == 0 );
             }
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Si quieres saber lo que ha pasado, por ejemplo para mostrar mensajes de error personalizados, puedes hacerlo, mediante los respectivos `else` de cada bloque `if`. Aquí lo he omitido, porque según la lógica del código, debe devolver `false` cuando algo haya fallado o no valide.

#### Nota sobre la seguridad

Tu código actual es altamente vulnerables a ataques de *inyección SQL*. Considera usar consultas preparadas para neutralizar ese grave peligro de seguridad.